# Exponential moving average before computing std

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, kalman-filter, data-preprocessing, filter

In which cases it would make sense to use exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA) **before**, for example, computing sample variance or other statistical analysis? Could you give an example when one needs to remove high frequencies before performing some analysis?

**My idea:**
A random walk + noise state-space model is equivalent to a EWMA, see, for example, discussion here:[What is the difference between Kalman filter and moving average?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16458/what-is-the-difference-between-kalman-filter-and-moving-average)

Therefore, if one first performs EWMA and then computing std, then it is an estimate of the transition std.

Comment: Note clear what transition std is. Not to be sarscastic but if you calculate the ewma and the compute the std, then it's the std of the ewma.

Comment: there is no sarcasm! what you said is correct! Then why do people do this transformation before? I understand that this way is not mathematically very accurate to estimate the transition std, I am just guessing.

Comment: I have a feeling that you are trying to do quadratic volatility estimation using EWMA. Basically EWMA can be used as a poor-man's GARCH. https://breakingdownfinance.com/finance-topics/risk-management/ewma/, https://www.investopedia.com/articles/07/ewma.asp

Comment: Dear  @CagdasOzgenc, yes, I am asking about using EWMA in the similar way as it is in the link you sent. Yes, I see that it similar to GARCH.

Comment: I sent you 2 links. EWMA on squared returns is basically GARCH with coefficients $\lambda$, and $1-\lambda$. That's all there is. So what is your question.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you! Before I was thinking about EWMA in that problems as a preprocessing tool.

Comment: The link you refer to in your question (EWMA, Kalman, ARMA equivalence) is related to mean estimation, not volatilty estimation. In this context we are filtering squared returns rather than returns themselves.

Comment: @ABK: I'm still not clear on your question but I hope it was answered by Cazdas Ozgenc.  Cazdas, thanks for link.

Comment: @ABK: I read your question again. . A lot of people use the EWMA as one would a moving average and, for $\lambda = 2/(n+1), they are pretty similar. But there's a much broader usage-perspective of the EWMA that shows up in econometrics when doing expectations modelling. See Sargent's text , "macro-economic theory", 1979 for all the gory details of what I mean by this.

Comment: Another book I highly recommend for the EWMA is Brown's text:  https://www.amazon.com/Smoothing-Forecasting-Prediction-Descrete-Time/dp/B00EOE0BQ6/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=brown+prediction%2C+smoothing&qid=1574186287&sr=8-2